# problem with the div tags

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have the following code

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<style type="text/css">
.setbgcolor{
background-color:blue;

}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function setbg(id){
document.getElementById(id).className = "setbgcolor";

}
</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div onclick="setbg(this.id)" id="bgcolor">Label1</div>
<div>Label2</div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Now, the problem is that- when i click on Label2, background color should be removed from the first div and should get applied to the second div. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you need something like a variable that stores the previously clicked div.

For example:

```
var previouslyClickedDiv = null;

function setbg(id){
    if (previouslyClickedDiv) { previouslyClickedDiv.className = ""; }
    var div = document.getElementById(id);
    div.className = "setbgcolor";
    previouslyClickedDiv = div;
}
```

Of course you can use a shorter variable name!

Answer (score 1):

There is no such event as, perhaps, `onunclick` in JavaScript; there's [`blur`/`onblur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.blur), but that requires the element to have had focus before it can be triggered.

That said, working on the assumption that you want **only** one `div` to be highlighted at any one time, the following works, albeit you'll have to tailor it to your specific needs:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('button'), curHighlights;

for (i=0; i<buttons.length; i++){
    buttons[i].onclick = function(){
        curHighlights = document.getElementsByClassName('bgcolor');
        if (curHighlights.length) {
            for (h=0; h<curHighlights.length; h++){
                // warning: the following removes _all_ class-names
                curHighlights[h].removeAttribute('class');
            }
        }
            this.className = 'bgcolor';
            this.setAttribute('data-state','1');

    };
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Rj9EC/).

I've removed the `onclick` event handlers from the in-line html, which makes it a little easier to maintain, although it does look quite messy.

For comparison, however, with jQuery the above could be condensed to:

```
$('.button').click(
    function(){
        $('.bgcolor').removeClass('bgcolor');
        $(this).addClass('bgcolor');
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Rj9EC/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Try to take a look at [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). It will make your life easier.

Comment: is it possible using javascript?

Comment: is there any event which is opposite of onclick?

Comment: Not sure what you mean...you click on something or you don't. There is no such thing as OnNoClick or something. You have methods as onmouseover or onmouseout...but i'm not sure if that's any help here.

Comment: I saw that in your question yes.